# The collection of some JSON data into a file

Tags: python, json, django, serialization, django-serializer

Can you give some idea how to do this collection. The problem is this: I get the JSON to assume the following

```
[{
    "pk": 1,
    "model": "store.book",
    "fields": {
        "name": "Mostly Harmless",
        "author": ["Douglas", "Adams"]
    }
}]
```

then unzip a file I save the data and close the file, the next time (this is a cycle) again receive again like JSON, for example, the following

```
[{
    "pk": 2,
    "model": "store.book",
    "fields": {
        "name": "Henry",
        "author": ["Hans"]
    }
}]
```

the second JSON must go into the same file in which it is located and the first. Here comes the problem how to do. At this stage, I do it in the following way, delete the brackets and put commas.Is there any smarter and a better way for this job?

Creating JSON-Serializing Django objects of a use. I would be very grateful if you share their ideas.

PS: It is important to use minimal memory. Assume that the file is around 50-60 GB and in memory to hold about 1 GB maximum

Comment: You want to fusion JSON data into a single file? Transform each piece of JSON data into Python objects by using `json` library, then fusion each other in a new object and finally save it in a file using again the library. Have a peek here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html or here http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/json.html

Comment: This means that you will keep all data in memory, because the data are very afraid of Out of Memory

Answer (score 0):

You would have to convert your data into JSON and store it into a file. Then read from the file again and append your new data to the object and again save it into the file. Here is some code that might be useful for you:

Use JSON. Documentation available at - http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

The first time you write into the file, you can use something like:

```
>>> import json
>>> fileW = open("filename.txt","w")
>>> json1 = [{
...     "pk": 1,
...     "model": "store.book",
...     "fields": {
...         "name": "Mostly Harmless",
...         "author": ["Douglas", "Adams"]
...     }
... }]
>>> json.dump(json1, fileW)
>>> fileW.close()
```

The following code could be used in a loop to read from the file and add data to it.

```
>>> fileLoop = open("filename.txt","r+")
>>> jsonFromFile = json.load(fileLoop)
>>> jsonFromFile
[{u'pk': 1, u'model': u'store.book', u'fields': {u'name': u'Mostly Harmless', u'author': [u'Douglas', u'Adams']}}]
>>> newJson = [{
...     "pk": 2,
...     "model": "store.book",
...     "fields": {
...         "name": "Henry",
...         "author": ["Hans"]
...     }
... }]
>>> jsonFromFile.append(newJson[0])
>>> jsonFromFile
[{u'pk': 1, u'model': u'store.book', u'fields': {u'name': u'Mostly Harmless', u'author': [u'Douglas', u'Adams']}}, {'pk': 2, 'model': 'store.book', 'fields': {'name': 'Henry', 'author': ['Hans']}}]
>>> json.dump(jsonFromFile, fileLoop)
>>> fileLoop.close()
```

Comment: This means to load gigabytes in memory, and I don't want to do it

Comment: In that case, I think @Till Hoffmann's answer would be more appropriate, since you wouldn't be reading it into memory.

Comment: Also include the memory constraint in your question.

Comment: Yes, but will again be in memory, and I do not want to open the file to read it, and he was loaded in memory

Comment: No, the file is not read into memory. Note that opening a file and reading a file are two distinct operations. `open` only returns a handle to the file. The data is only read into memory when you call `read`.

Comment: @TillHoffmann Are you saying that f. seek (length-1) won't read the file and took me straight to the end?

Comment: If I am not wrong, using methods like the read/readline only will load the data into memory. Seek would not.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to parse the JSON because you are only storing it. The following (a) creates a file and (b) appends text to the file in each cycle.

```
from os.path import getsize

def init(filename):
    """
    Creates a new file and sets its content to "[]".
    """
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        f.write("[]")
        f.close()

def append(filename, text):
    """
    Appends a JSON to a file that has been initialised with `init`.
    """
    length = getsize(filename) #Figure out the number of characters in the file
    with open(filename, 'r+') as f:
        f.seek(length - 1) #Go to the end of the file
        if length > 2: #Insert a delimiter if this is not the first JSON
            f.write(",\n")
        f.write(text[1:-1]) #Append the JSON
        f.write("]") #Write a closing bracket
        f.close()

filename = "temp.txt"
init(filename)

while mycondition:
    append(filename, getjson())
```

If you did not have to save the JSON after each cycle, you could do the following

```
jsons = []
while mycondition:
    jsons.append(getjson()[1:-1])

with open("temp.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write("[")
    f.write(",".join(jsons))
    f.write("]")
    f.close()
```

Comment: I'm afraid that it will keep a lot of data in memory. I EDIT MY QUESTION

Answer (score 0):

To avoid creating multigigabytes objects, you could store each object on a separate line. It requires you to dump each object without newlines used for formatting (json strings themselves may use `\n` (two chars) as usual):

```
import json

with open('output.txt', 'a') as file: # open the file in the append mode
    json.dump(obj, file, 
              separators=',:') # the most compact representation by default
    file.write("\n")
```